# Idea can't correct autocomplete text

Tags: annotations, intellij-idea

I'm writing small web application on java with hibernate, and I see strange thing - when for example I'm write

```
@ID
```

or

```
@Id
```

My IDE(Idea) automaticly change it into correct form `@Id`
But when I'm writing like `@id` it tells me that it is an error and it cann't find correct form.
I'm searching in settings but can't find something that help Ide to fix this problem

May be someone know how to fix this?
Thanks)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Settings` | `Editor` | `Code Completion` | **Case sensitive completion**: **None**.